# Why return of negative exist in pkcs7_padding library

Tags: c, aes, padding, pkcs#7, cbc-mode

IN  pkcs7_padding.c

from  [enter link description here](https://github.com/bonybrown/tiny-AES128-C/blob/master/pkcs7_padding.c)

and [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/bingoohuang/100934dc8561417c6e71daefb43effc8)

```
if( data_length + pad_byte > buffer_size ){
    return -pad_byte;
  }
```

Sorry i would like to know whats the meaning of the return of the "-pad_byte" ?
and why this code is needed in here?
thanks

Comment: You should really ask the maintainer of the code and not us. But it looks like a bug to me. The [API header](https://gist.github.com/bingoohuang/100934dc8561417c6e71daefb43effc8#file-pkcs7_padding-h-L11) documents the return value for `pkcs7_padding_pad_buffer` as: "Returns the number of pad bytes added, or zero if the buffer size is not large enough". So either the code is wrong or the comment is wrong.

Comment: The negative value probably indicates "there isn't space for the padding, but the absolute value of the returned number is the amount of padding that would be needed".

Comment: how can i raise an issue in the github? in the maintainer?